# Delay in playing HTML5 audio file on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, android-mediaplayer, media

I am making a web app, and i needed to add a short sound when a button is being clicked.

the file is in mp3 format and around 24kb in size, i didnt want to use javascript to create the element so i added it to the DOM and used CSS to hide it, also i added preload="auto" so it gets loaded with the DOM

```
<audio id="click" preload style="display:none;"> 
   <source src="sound/click.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

in the javascript, i have something like:

```
var clickSound = $('#click')[0];
```

then in a function that listens to an even click on a button i have:

```
function(){
  clickSound.play();
}
```

this works fine on my computer (firefox, chrome), but on mobile after clicking the trigger button, it will wait for like 3 seconds before it plays for the first time, and *will now play instantly after the first delayed play*.

**Update:**

i noticed even if i navigate to the mp3 file on my mobile like this http://example.com/sound/click.mp3 and click on play, it still delays, seems like it had to buffer.

anyway around this problem?

#### Complete Example:

[Here is a jsFiddle for mobile testing.](http://jsfiddle.net/dtggnw9f/1/show/)

```js
var clickSound = document.getElementById('click');
var play = document.getElementById('play');

play.addEventListener('click', function() {
      clickSound.play();
}, false);
```

```html
<audio id="click" preload>
  <source src="http://scriveit.com/sound/click.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>


<input id="play" type="button" value="play sound">
```

Comment: This is interesting. It would make things easier if you included a complete example including the mp3 that can just be run by us without having to find a suitable mp3 to re-create this ourselves.

Comment: @misterManSam i am not allowed to add external links

Comment: Thanks but same delay on mobile devices, works fine on PC

Comment: It wasn't meant to fix the problem! Just adding it for testing purposes :) The fiddle recreates the problem. For me there is ~ 30 seconds wait for very first play, no delay after that. There is a subsequent ~ 3 seconds delay on refresh and first play. Nexus 4 Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing that for smaller audio files is pre-loading the file as a blob:

```
<button>play</button>
<audio></audio>
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'click.mp3', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
xhr.onload = function () {
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);  
};
xhr.send();
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    audio.play();
};
</script>
```

Please note that this requires XHR2 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) and Blob URLs (http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls) and that the same origin policy applies here. Moreover, you should make sure that the file is sent with some strong caching headers to prevent that the clients reloads the file with every request.

**Edit:** Another approach is using Data URLs (see http://jsfiddle.net/apo299od/):

```
<button>play</button>
<audio></audio>
<script>
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.src = 'data:audio/mp3;base64,SUQzBAAAAAA...';
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    audio.play();
};
</script>
```

The disadvantages here are that it is harder to maintain and that it will inflate your response size by 33%.

Comment: Could you add this into a working jsFiddle that can be tested on mobile devices?

Comment: @Joel thanks, i will try that now and see, but any reason why this is happening? actually i just started learning JS

Comment: @user2666633 I guess it is to save bandwidth on mobile devices. Don't forget to use the prefixed version of URL for older browsers.

Comment: @misterManSam, if you provide me a mp3 file with CORS headers :-) The following example will behave similar, but uses a data URL (which would be another approach to solve the problem): http://jsfiddle.net/apo299od/

Comment: The fiddle works great on mobile exactly as is +1  You should add it to your answer as another approach :)

Comment: works great, on mobile, will implement the data URLs